TRS Animation Distorted between Keyframes, works directly interpolating matrices
I'm working with a model + animation and I'm having trouble getting the animation to function properly when I decompose the animation key frames into TRS and import into blender. When I render the model and animation in a custom program and simply linearly interpolate the matrices everything looks great.
The decomposed key frame matrices look great in blender as well, but as soon as I go to an interpolated frame the model becomes distorted. I've made sure that the quaternions are normalized and that the dot product of the quaternions are all of the same sign (indicating they are on the same hemisphere I believe?) with the same graphical result each time. I'm thinking it might be a quaternion issue because the scale of the model appears to be visually correct and the position of the start and end keyframe seem normal, and translation is the most straight forward to extract from the transformation matrix.
I've also read several things about how just interpolating the matrices directly, without decomposing, may lead to distortion because of shear. I seem to be experiencing the reverse of that, getting the distortion because I'm decomposing. Are there any known animation systems that rely on shear to look proper?
Gif showing stepping through the keyframes in blender:

Gif showing stepping through interpolated frames in blender. Notice the hand/forearms on both arms are distorted. Second GIF here shows the first few frames more slowly.


I think I've narrowed the offending bones down to the palm and forearm bones in both arms. Here is a screen shot showing the curves for the left palm bone. I'm not familiar enough with animating to recognize what might be going on here. This is a normalized view of the curves. :

Same curve without normalization to show magnitude of translation:

Here is a link to the blend file as well, if you would like to poke around yourselves.
This model comes from a fairly old game and other resources I've found seem to indicate that this was originally animated using 3dsmax 5, or around that era, if its relevant.
Appreciate anything any one has to offer! Thanks!
